# aplicaciones portables

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Muy buen día, quisiera saber si es posible poder realizar aplicaciones portables es decir que se ejecuten en una USB y no tengan que instalarse en una computador, utilizando python y una base de datos para poder almacenar datos valga la redundancia, e googleado mucho y no encuentro respuesta.
La idea es realizar una app para que un profesor pueda llevar el registro diario de los aportes de sus estudiantes como tareas, exámenes, lecciones etc.
Muchas gracias..

Answer (score 0):

Se puede si, creando un ejecutable, un .exe, puede ser con pyinstaller por ejemplo. Usas una carpeta con el .exe y el .txt o .csv, o cual sea el formato de tu base de datos.